# Using a Netgear WGR614v9 to extend wireless signal from Netgear DG934GT

Tags: networking, repeater, wireless-networking

I'm wondering if someone could please provide me the steps for extending/repeating my wirless signal so that I can have greater wireless range throughout my house.

I have 2 wirless Netgear routers, a DG934GT ADSL router (base unit) and WGR614v9 cable router (repeater). I've flashed both routers with the latest firmware and have turned on the wireless repeating function in the WGR614v9 but I can't get internet access when connected to the repeater, I can only get it when connected to the base unit.

Can this be achieved by running an ethernet cable between the two routers as thus far I've only tried to get them to contact each other wirelessly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that WGR614v9 is communicating with the DG934GT? Maybe routers logs would help?
For the future buy devices that support WDS - at least it's easyer to configure.

It's hard to give advices when you can't see routers configuration. Maybe this would help:

kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/960

kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1016

kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1019/related/1

p.s. I think the best way is to write a letter to Netgear TechSup. They'll anser you in 24 hours. Ask them to send you step by step instruction.